# What does DivergentArrayError means in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While updating a document with embedded arrays, I am getting **DivergentArrayError**. I am updating array elements of the document.

Can someone please help me by explaining what does this error mean. I am not able to find any relevant information anywhere :(.

Comment: please show your code and paste the error stack.

Comment: Perhaps [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2031) may shed some light on why that error is being thrown. It looks like it may happen when you return and modify a filtered array from a document.